# was... has been vs was... had been

Tags: tenses, past-perfect

I wrote a sentence by myself as follows:

> It WAS acclaimed as a masterpiece that HAD changed the world.

I am confused if the "had changed" here is correct because I intended to say "has changed", but I am not sure if it needs to agree with the past tense "was" in the main clause.

Which one is correct? Is there another preferable way to say?

Comment: both are correct. it depends on what you mean. If the change is still relevant, then has changed reflects that it is still active in the present time. if you are talking about some  ancient change, then had changed could mean it's not so relevant in current context

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you.